# Characterization Problem Involving Inner Product

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Let us consider the set $\mathbb{L}^{n} = \{\textbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}_{\geq0};\sum x_{i} = 1\}$ and the vector $\textbf{w}_{n} = \left(0,\frac{1}{n-1},\frac{2}{n-1},\ldots,\frac{n-2}{n-1},1\right)$. I would be extremely grateful if someone could provide me an explicit relation among the coordinates of $\textbf{x}\in\mathbb{L}^{n}$ and $\textbf{y}\in\mathbb{L}^{n}$ satisfying $\langle\textbf{x}-\textbf{y},\textbf{w}_{n}\rangle = 0$. It works for $\textbf{x} = (0.7,0.2,0.1)$ and $\textbf{y} = (0.6,0.4,0)$, for example. But it does not hold when $\textbf{x} = (0.5,0.4,0.1)$ and $\textbf{y} = (0.6,0.3,0.1)$, for instance. Thank you in advance for any contribution.

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer?

Comment: Thank you for the contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do the case $n=3$. Then $w_3=(0,1/2,1)$. The vectors $v$ such that $v\cdot w=0$ and $v\cdot(1,1,1)=0$ form a vector space with basis $(1,-2,1)$. So the relation between $x$ and $y$ is $x=y+t(1,-2,1)$ for some real $t$. In terms of coordinates, this is $x_1=y_1+t$, $x_2=y_2-2t$, $x_3=y_3+t$. In your example, $t=1/10$.